# Xpaths div changing after every new build

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

Im currently auotmating an web application using selenium java.For locating the elements Iam using relative xpaths. I am facing a problem regularly when ever I get a new build my xpath div values are changing.
E.x:

Build 1:

```
//*[@id='container']/div/div/div/div/div[5]/div/ul/li[1]/div/ul/li[13]/button
```

Build 2:

```
//*[@id='container']/div/div/div/div/div[6]/div/ul/li[1]/div/ul/li[13]/button
```

How can we make this xpath work for every build? Even we are using this xpath for 'for loops' as well.

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
    com.click("xpath","/html[1]/body[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[4]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/ul[1]/li[1]/div[2]/div[1]/ul[1]/li["+ i + "]/div[1]/span[2]/div[1]");         
}
```

Is there any solution to overcome this issue?

HTML Code:

```
<div id="container" xpath="1"><div><div class="ice-theme-provider light-theme css-aw120u e9snama0" data-automation-active-theme-name="light"><div tabindex="-1"><div class="css-1enaoom" data-automation-id="console" data-console-id="0" role="presentation"><div data-automation-id="application-menu-bar" class="css-1f2kwet"><ul class="css-qq4041" data-automation-id="system-menu"><li class="css-1tx6twl"><button type="button" class="ice-button css-5nd6tx e66scw10">File</button></li><li class="css-1tx6twl"><button type="button" class="ice-button css-5nd6tx e66scw10">Preferences</button></li><li class="css-1tx6twl"><button type="button" class="ice-button css-5nd6tx e66scw10">Connect Utils</button></li><li class="css-1tx6twl"><button type="button" class="ice-button css-5nd6tx e66scw10">Help</button></li></ul><span class="css-132uuf9"></span><button title="Tab Sorting: Manual (unsorted)" type="button" class="ice-button css-151om0c e66scw10">MANUAL</button><button title="click to unlock the layout"

<button aria-disabled="false" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" type="button" class="ice-button e12espz23 css-1gkebzc e66scw10" style="" xpath="1"><span>Mark Field<span width="square" class="ice-icon ice-icon-caret-right css-19ah4i1 e5j0fb80"><svg viewBox="576 0 576 1792"><path d="M1152 896q0 26-19 45l-448 448q-19 19-45 19t-45-19-19-45v-896q0-26 19-45t45-19 45 19l448 448q19 19 19 45z"></path></svg></span></span></button>
```

Comment: I think there should a better way to write the xpath that you are using. Please share the html of the button starting from `[@id='container']` element.

Comment: Its good if you ask developers to add id attribute to intractable elements like button, and u can use the id to locate the same.

Answer (score 0):

use below.

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@title='click to unlock the layout']")).click();
```

}

Comment: Hi @arkadiyala this did not worked as 'clicking on corporate reference sub options' is not the text in the xpath..

Answer (score 0):

An XPath expression with number data type inside a predicate is just an abbreviated form for comparison against `position()` function.

You might use as well this XPath only expression:

```
/html[1]/body[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[4]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]
  /div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/ul[1]/li[1]/div[2]/div[1]/ul[1]
      /li[position() <= 4]/div[1]/span[2]/div[1]
```

Comment: Hi @Alejandro as my div values are changing after every new build even-though when I change to position() it may not work..

Comment: @krishna I don't understand your comment. This expression is going to be the same as `for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {com.click("xpath","/html[1]/body[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[4]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/ul[1]/li[1]/div[2]/div[1]/ul[1]/li["+ i + "]/div[1]/span[2]/div[1]");}` every time.

Comment: yes but when ever my build changes my xpath div values are changing..so it will work fine now once my build changes it will not work..

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the content inside the tag and also the text between the tag so that you could get the required Web Element.
This is not a good approach since it will change the structure of the program and will face a issue as you are facing now.

- I prefer you use a parameter which is inside the tag like
  **id,name,class,placeholder** etc.
  ex:- xpath= " //input[@name='email'] "
- Text between the tag like
  xpath= "//a[contains(text(),'This is an example')]"

This would solve most of the problem.

Try it out it will help you.

Reach out to me if you have any doubts.